# Why does $\operatorname{Proj} k[x, y]/(xy)$ consist of only two points?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

In the book *Introduction to Schemes* by Ellingsrud and Ottem it's claimed that if $R = k[x, y]/(xy)$, then $\operatorname{Proj} R$ consists of just two points.

I assume that the authors here are working with an algebraically closed field $k$. The argument that the authors give is the following -

> "$\operatorname{Proj} R$ is obtained by gluing $\operatorname{Spec} (R_{(x)})$ and $\operatorname{Spec} (R_{(y)})$ together. Now, $$R_{(x)} = k[x, y]_{(x)}/(xy) =  k[x, y]_{(x)}/(y) = k[x]_{(x)} =k$$ and the corresponding chart of $\operatorname{Proj} R$ is just $\operatorname{Spec} k$. Similarly, the other chart $\operatorname{Spec}(R_{(y)})$ also equals $\operatorname{Spec} k$. We have $R_{(xy)} = 0$, so the overlap is empty, and it ensures that $\operatorname{Proj} R$ consists of the two points."

So here (partly) what the authors are saying is that $D_+((x)) = \operatorname{Spec} (R_{(x)}) = \operatorname{Spec} k$ which is a singleton and similarly $D_+((y)) = \operatorname{Spec} (R_{(y)}) = \operatorname{Spec} k$. Also $\operatorname{Spec}(R_{(xy)}) = D_+((x\cdot y)) = D_+((x))\cap D_+((y))$ *(I think this equality holds as it holds in the case of the usual Zariski topology for $\operatorname{Spec}$ but I am not fully sure)* and this is what the authors are talking about when they say "overlap".

Now I have essentially two main questions.

1. How do we know that $\operatorname{Proj} R$ is obtained by gluing $\operatorname{Spec} (R_{(x)})$ and $\operatorname{Spec} (R_{(y)})$ together?
2. Why do the two equalities $R_{(x)} = k[x, y]_{(x)}/(xy) =  k[x, y]_{(x)}/(y)$ hold?

Comment: #1 is direct from the construction of Proj as a scheme. Have you covered that?

Comment: For 2.: the first equality holds because localization is an exact functor, so it commutes with taking quotients. In other words, $R_{(x)}$ is obtained from quotienting first and then localizing, while in $k[x, y]_{(x)}/(xy)$ we localize first and then quotient, and these are isomorphic by exactness. The second equality holds because $x$ is a unit in $k[x,y]_{(x)}$, so the ideals $(xy)$ and $(y)$ are equal. (The authors use $R_{(x)}$ to denote the degree $0$ part of $R_x$ which seems like bad notation to me, since $R_{(x)}$ often means the localization of $R$ at the complement of $(x)$.)

Comment: @KReiser In the construction I saw of $\operatorname{Proj} B$ it was, as a set, the set of homogenous prime ideals of $B$ not containing the irrelevant ideal and then we put a sort of Zariski topology on it and then it becomes a topological space and we then define the structure sheaf on it analogously to $\operatorname{Spec} A$. I've since seen that we can also define $$\operatorname{Proj} B = \bigcup_{a \in B_d, d > 0} D_+(a)$$ and then view $\operatorname{Proj} B$ as glued from the schemes $D_+(a)$. So I'm assuming the latter is the way we view the construction for the question at hand.

Comment: @ViktorVaughn Thank you *very* much for that clear explanation!

Comment: Alternatively, $\operatorname{Proj}(R)$ corresponds to the set of homogeneous ideals in $k[x,y]$ containing $(xy)$ but not containing $(x,y)$, so it is just $(x)$ and $(y)$ since $k$ is algebraically closed. (But of course this only determines $\operatorname{Proj}(R)$ as a topological space.)

Comment: When you endow $\operatorname{Proj}(R)$ with a structure sheaf, you probably already implicitly saw the gluing that you mention afterwards (and suggested by KReiser). To show that it is a scheme, you have to make sure that it is locally an affine scheme after all.

Also, the equality $D_+(xy) = D_+(x) \cap D_+(y)$ indeed holds and the proof is exactly the same as in the affine case.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the formality described in the previous answers, say we take any cone  $C \subset \mathbb{A}^n$, where cone means heuristically that if a point is in $C$ then so is the whole line through the origin and that point. More algebraically, we could say C is a closed subscheme defined by a homogeneous ideal. Then Proj C is just the space of lines in C.

So here k[x, y]/(xy) corresponds to the union of the x and y axes in the plane. What are the lines of this union? Just these two axes, the two points of the corresponding Proj.